# Non Reproducible results even after setting the seed value (Python API of Microsoft CNTK)

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, cntk

Previously, I mentioned that there aren't any options available to define a seed value in Branscripts for CNTK sequential machine learning models[1]. Hence I migrated my code to Python API (CNTK), which gives more fine-grained options when defining the seed values of sequential machine learning models. Below are the instances that I have used random initialization in my implementation (and set the corresponding seed value as well)

// CNTK imports

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
import math as m

from cntk.device import *
from cntk import Trainer
from cntk.layers import * 

import cntk
import cntk.ops as o
import cntk.layers as l
```

//defining the random seed

```
np.random.seed(8888)
random.seed(8888)
```

// Defining input and output training vectors

```
input_array_df = np.asarray(input_split_df[1:len(input_split_df)], dtype=np.float32)
output_array_df = np.asarray(output_df_df[1:len(output_df_df)], dtype=np.float32)
tup=(input_array_df, output_array_df)
listOfTuplesOfInputsLabels.append(tup)
```

//shuffling the input vector

```
 random.shuffle(listOfTuplesOfInputsLabels)
```

//Defining sequential model

```
num_minibatches = len(features) // minibatch_size
    epoch_size = len(features)*1

    feature = o.input_variable((input_dim),np.float32)
    label = o.input_variable((output_dim),np.float32)

    netout=Sequential([For(range(1), lambda i: Recurrence(LSTM(lstm_cell_dimension,use_peepholes=LSTM_USE_PEEPHOLES,init=glorot_uniform(seed=8888)))),Dense(output_dim,bias=BIAS,init=glorot_uniform(seed=8888))])(feature)

    learner = momentum_sgd(netout.parameters, lr = learning_rate_schedule([(4,0.003),(16,0.002)], unit=UnitType.sample,epoch_size=epoch_size),
                               momentum=momentum_as_time_constant_schedule(minibatch_size / -m.log(0.9)), gaussian_noise_injection_std_dev = gaussian_noise,l2_regularization_weight =l2_regularization_weight)
```

//Splitting into mini batches

```
tf = np.array_split(features,num_minibatches)
tl = np.array_split(labels,num_minibatches)
```

//Train

```
features = np.ascontiguousarray(tf[i%num_minibatches])
labels = np.ascontiguousarray(tl[i%num_minibatches])
trainer.train_minibatch({feature : features, label : labels})
```

Unfortunately, even though I was able to successfully define the seed value in my code, I could still observe some smaller variations in my final result. Is this because of the floating point calculations? or could you find anything in my code that I should have set the seed value, which I haven't done it already?

Thanks !

[1] [Defining a seed value in Branscripts for CNTK sequential machine learning models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462506/defining-a-seed-value-in-branscripts-for-cntk-sequential-machine-learning-models)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the below:

```
from _cntk_py import set_fixed_random_seed, force_deterministic_algorithms
set_fixed_random_seed(1)
force_deterministic_algorithms()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response !. I posted this question on CNTK's Github profile as well [Github Question](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/1965#issuecomment-306141219), where one of the suggestions was the same as you stated above. But unfortunately, even though this has reduced the initial variance of results comparatively, still I could observe small variances in my final output matrix.

Comment: Apparently in that page, one of the developers has instructed to call **cntk.cntk_py.set_fixed_random_seed(1)** directly instead of using _cntk_py

Comment: I was able to fix this issue by upgrading my code to CNTK 2.0. You can find the detail steps that I followed to fix this issue in the question that I have posted on the CNTK's GitHub profile (https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/1965)